# getGeneratedKeys() after PreparedStatement.executeBatch()

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to `INSERT` several rows using a `PreparedStatement`:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(query,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

for(Element e:listOfElements){
    ps.setString(1,this.col_val_1);
    ps.setString(2,this.col_val_2);
    ps.setInt(3,this.col_val_3);

    ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

At this point, whent I expect to get the PK's generated for each `INSERT`, I get this `SQLServerException`:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement must be executed before any results can be obtained.
```

I expected to get a ResultSet with one row for each insert performed, so I could get each PK generated.

Am I expecting wrong? Am I doing something wrong? Can it be done in a different way using batch execution?

Comment: Is the `INSERT`s by any chance transaction'ed?

Comment: If you ask if `INSERT`s are executed successfully, yes. The problem occurs when I want to retrieved its keys.

Comment: I mean that the batch might need to be `commit()`'ed before you can obtain the generated keys.

Comment: I've tried to force a `con.commit();` before getting the keys and the problem persists. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Support for `getGeneratedKeys()` on batch execution is implementation defined according to the JDBC spec. Most likely the SQL Server driver does not support it for batch execution.

I tried to look for an explicit statement on the Microsoft site, but couldn't find it. This old (2007) forum post on MSDN does state that it isn't supported: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/6cbf5eea-e5b9-4519-8e86-f4b65ce3f8e1

Comment: That's exactly what happens: I can see the result of each `INSERT` by getting the result of `executeBatch()` in a `int []` variable, but I also wanted to get the inserted keys in order to log them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I didn't find any explicit statement saying it isn't supported (i had my suspicions, but I wasn't sure).

Comment: The SQL Server JDBC driver team at Microsoft has identified this as a [feature request for a future release](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/245).