# java: retrieve keys after executeBatch() in H2

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I am trying to retrieve generated keys from an `executeBatch()` transaction but I only get the last key to be added.

this is my code:

```
        PreparedStatement ps_insert = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);          
        for (int i = 0 ; i < adding_dates.length ; i++){
            ps_insert.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(consultant_id));
            ps_insert.setDate(2, adding_dates[i]);
            ps_insert.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(room_id));
            ps_insert.addBatch();
        }
        ps_insert.executeBatch();
        ResultSet rs = ps_insert.getGeneratedKeys(); //<-- Only the last key retrieved
        conn.commit();
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Apologies for not mentioning that I use H2 (http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database in embedded mode.

Comment: Which database/JDBC driver are you using? It is probably JDBC implementation problem.

Comment: Just to create full picture show please rs iteration code

Comment: @partlov you are right. Some JDBC implementation do not support getGeneratedKeys() feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641832/getgeneratedkeys-after-preparedstatement-executebatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to H2 [jdbc driver javadocs](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcStatement.html#getGeneratedKeys), this is the normal behaviour:

> Return a result set that **contains the last generated auto-increment**
>   key for this connection, if there was one. If no key was generated by
>   the last modification statement, then an empty result set is returned.
>   The returned result set only contains the data for the very last row.

Comment: It shouldn't considered normal behavior, but rather limitation. They should implement this according to JDBC specification, so their driver is incomplete.

Comment: Support has been implemented since version 1.4.191. See: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/156

Answer (score 1):

You must iterate the `ResultSet` to retrieve the keys.

```
  PreparedStatement ps_insert = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);          
    for (int i = 0 ; i < adding_dates.length ; i++){
        ps_insert.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(consultant_id));
        ps_insert.setDate(2, adding_dates[i]);
        ps_insert.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(room_id));
        ps_insert.addBatch();
    }
    ps_insert.executeBatch();
    ResultSet rs = ps_insert.getGeneratedKeys(); //<-- Only the last key retrieved

    if (rs.next()) {
       ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
       int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

       do {
           for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
             String key = rs.getString(i);
             System.out.println("key " + i + "is " + key);
           }
       }
      while (rs.next();)
     } 

    conn.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. `getGeneratedKeys()` returns a ResultSet, so iteration is necessary (and was the first thing I tried). Sorry I didn't mention that earlier. I tried your iteration, though but it didn't work, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of H2 implementation. This is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/issues/detail?id=357).

For now use inserts/updates without batch, or query generated keys somehow through select.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing a session/connection between 2 threads, and two of those threads try to execute statements at the same time, then you might see this kind of problem.

You probably need to either (a) use a connection pool or (b) synchronise your entire access to the DB.

for instance for option (b)

put a `synchronize` token infront of your method to make it thread safe

Just a thought as i dont know you complete execution context

Comment: Thank you. My implementation is very simple, no sharing connections, just an application with its embedded file.